# How can I run my app compiled in Xcode 7.3.1 on the iOS 10 Simulator

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

So, because of all the naming changes my current project doesn't run on Xcode 8 beta and has lots of compilation errors that I cannot easily get rid of.

Is there a way to at least run a compiled version that was made in XCode 7.3.1 on the iOS10 Simulator?

Comment: Are you trying to run your project using the Swift 3 compiler? Try using Swift 2.3 which probably won't give you [many] errors.

Comment: No I tried the 2.3 too. Unfortunately even using swift 2.3 fails due to unfixable conflicts in third party libraries.

Answer (score 2):

The trick is to create a symbolic link the DeviceSupport folder from the beta to the stable version

**From terminal**

```
ln -s /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/10.0\ \(14A5261u\) /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport
```

Comment: I just tried that. Unfortunately no new Simulators show up in the "Devices" sections. Are there any additional steps that have to be performed?

Comment: in the "DeviceSupport" of Xcode-beta must be a simulator, otherwise should be reinstall Xcode-beta

Comment: Make sure to use autocompletion in your bash or to look up the exact build number of 10.0 bundled with your current Xcode-beta.app